# How to solve an integral with a differential elevated to the nth power

Tags: integration, quantum-mechanics

I'm solving a quantum mechanics problem and I've got the following integral as a result

$$ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \, \delta \left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right) \, \left(x-x_0 \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right)^n \, e^{-(x/x_0)^2/2} \, dx. $$

It should be pretty straightforward to evaluate, thanks to the delta function, however I can't due to the differential operator. My professor said there was a way to get rid of the operator, but couldn't remember it.

Comment: Can you clean up the notation? There is some substantial ambiguity here, for example with what exactly is multiplying the differential operator.

Comment: I understand a symbolic $n$th power of an operator.  But what is $*$?  In mathematics, it is probably a convolution.  In computer language, it is probably multiplication.  How about doing the case $n=1$ for us;  that may help us understand what you wrote.

Comment: What was the original expression in terms of kets and operators ? It is often easier to carry algebraic manipulations on those beforehand than computing the integral straightforwardly. The operator in question looks like an annihilation operator. You might also try to compute the first cases, deduce a formula from them and finally prove it by recurrence.

Comment: The original expression was the squared modulus of a bra n and a state ket a, with the delta function being the wave function and the rest of the expression being the equation 2.3.32 of sakurai's modern quantum mechanics (2nd edition)

Answer (score 4):

The essence of the problem is:

Using an operator form of the Hermite polynomials,
$$ H_{n}(y) = e^{y^2/2} \, \left(y - \frac{d}{dy}\right)^n \, e^{-y^2/2}. $$
Letting $y = x/a$ leads to
$$ a^n \, e^{-x^2/(2 a^2)} \, H_{n}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) = \left(x - a^2 \, \frac{d}{dx}\right)^n \, e^{-x^2/(2 a^2)} $$
and
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \, \delta \left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right) \, \left(x - a^{2} \ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right)^n \, e^{-(x/a)^2/2} \, dx = a^{n} \, e^{-L^2/(8 a^{2})} \, H_{n}\left(\frac{L}{2 a}\right). $$

Comment: How can I find anything on the operator form of the hermite polynomials?

Comment: @HectorFreire   MathWorld [Hermite Polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html) equation (31) gives the ref Arfken 1985, pp. 712-713 and 720.

Comment: In physics terms this operator form demonstrates how, in position space, the $n$th excited oscillator state is found by $n$ applications of the creation operator to the ground state. More precisely, one has $$\langle y |\phi_n\rangle=H_n(y)e^{-y^2/2}=\langle y |a^n|\phi_0\rangle=(y-d/dy)^n e^{-y^2/2}$$ up to some tedious factors and rescaling.